# midi controller setup - no sound

Tags: release-juno, audio, music

I was attracted to Elementary OS for the features.  Running Juno on a laptop.
I'm trying to get a midi controller to playback sound.  It is a M-Audio Radium 49 and connects via USB.  The lsusb program finds the controller when it
is pulled in as 'Midiman M-Audio Keyboard loader'.

I cannot find the correct combination of software, synths, patches and sound fonts to get it to make any sound.
I do have a windows machine and plug it in and make sounds with MuseScore.  The same setup on Elementary OS doesn't produce any sounds.

As a side note, I did get a USB audio interface running with Ardour without anything other than adding my user to the audio group.

It would be great to have a few Audio tutorials specific to recording and Digital Audio Workstation setups.

Answer (score 0):

This is not related to the Music app, but MIDI controllers do not produce sound, they control midi software or hardware. You will need to familiarize yourself with the Jack Audio Connection Kit and Alsa Sequencer. Check youtube, there are a lot of linux audio tutorials.